# Excel Array formula, use info from one IF result as criteria in another IF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

### Context

I'm building a financial dashboard, but I'm having troubles to get a formula that fit my client's need.

I'm consolidating amount in different currencies, but for a special indicator,
I need to build a **YTD with the Exchange Rate of the last month**.

Something like :

```
(Amount_$_Jan + Amount_$_Feb)*ExRate_$_Feb + (Amount_£_Jan + Amount_£_Feb)*ExRate_£_Feb
```

OR

```
(Amount_$_Jan + Amount_$_Feb + Amount_$_Mar)*ExRate_$_Mar + (Amount_£_Jan + Amount_£_Feb + Amount_£_Mar)*ExRate_£_Mar
```

---

### My issue

In the data, I have multiple currencies and they'll be more to come, so I cannot list the currencies.

I'm trying to :

- **get the value of the currency of each line that matches the criteria of the first `IF`**
- **to use it in my second `IF` to find the exchange range for that currency** 
  for the month I'm calculating for,
  with: `Named_Rg[Currency]=Named_Rg[Currency]`

which is **obviously always true**, but it is the only syntax I've tried that I could validate...

I've tried :

- `Named_Rg[Currency]=[@[Currency]]`
- `Named_Rg[Currency]=[Currency]`

But both are giving errors (I'm using that formula outside of the table `Named_Rg`)

I know I can write a function in VBA, but I'd prefer to keep an `xlsx`.

---

### My formula

I've removed some tests, like testing the year, which are not pertinent for the question.

I'm using it on a another sheet that the one where the table `Named_Rg` is :

```
{=SUM(IF(Named_Rg[Month]<=MONTH(X$5);Named_Rg[Amount]*IF(AND(Named_Rg[Month]=MONTH(X$5);Named_Rg[Currency]=Named_Rg[Currency]);Named_Rg[Chg to €];0);0))}
```

How can I refer to the Row/Currency found with the first `IF` in the second one?

### Sample Data

That is just a sample, I'll have multiples rows per month and currency.

```
Year    Month   Currency    Chg to €    Amount
2017    1       EUR         1           20
2017    1       USD         0.6         30
2017    1       LST         2           40
2017    2       EUR         1           200
2017    2       USD         0.7         300
2017    2       LST         2.2         400
2017    3       EUR         1           2000
2017    3       USD         0.8         3000
2017    3       LST         2.4         4000
```

CSV format :

```
Year;Month;Currency;Chg to €;Amount
2017;1;EUR;1;20
2017;1;USD;0.6;30
2017;1;LST;2;40
2017;2;EUR;1;200
2017;2;USD;0.7;300
2017;2;LST;2.2;400
2017;3;EUR;1;2000
2017;3;USD;0.8;3000
2017;3;LST;2.4;4000
```

### Expected results :

YTD last chg (Jan) : **118** = 20*1+30*0.6+40*2
YTD last chg (Feb) : **1419** = (20+200)*1+(30+300)*0.7+(40+400)*2.2
YTD last chg (Mar) : **15540** = (20+200+2000)*1+(30+300+3000)*0.8+(40+400+4000)*2.4

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the worksheet (and show where the named ranges are)? I never heard of an Excel Formula 'MOIS', is it mistyped?

Comment: What does [@[Currency]] mean?

Comment: @z32a7ul : I just forgot to change it in English, `MOIS` is `MONTH`. I'm making a data sample right now. As for `[@[Currency]]`, create a table and make a formula in there, it is referring to a column by name inside that table.

Comment: Can you post something about the desired output, too? I don't see if it is going to be a single cell or a table. What is the logic behind multiplying the amount of Jan+Feb with the rate of Feb instead of Jan * Jan + Feb * Feb? What do you do in Mar? Jan+Feb+Mar or Feb+Mar or Jan+Mar?

Comment: @z32a7ul : See the edit! ;) I don't see the logic either, but it is a mandatory Financial indicator that is asked by regulation authorities.

Comment: If manually, using the data, please post the formula you used to get January; like `((20+30+40)*1)+(...` just so I can understand better your formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner : Done, I've also added a *literal* example for March at the start of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array formula do not like the `AND()` or `OR()` operators.  They need to be substituted with `*` or `+` respectively.

So your:

```
AND(Named_Rg[Month]=MONTH(X$5);Named_Rg[Currency]=Named_Rg[Currency])
```

Should be:

```
(Named_Rg[Month]=MONTH(X$5))*(Named_Rg[Currency]=Named_Rg[@Currency])
```

So the formula would be:

```
=SUM(IF(Named_Rg[Month]<=MONTH(X$5);Named_Rg[Amount]*IF((Named_Rg[Month]=MONTH(X$5))*(Named_Rg[Currency]=Named_Rg[@Currency]);Named_Rg[Chg to €])))
```

Remember that this is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

[image]

---

But I think you want this formula instead to get the desired output:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Named_Rg[Amount],Named_Rg[Month],"<=" & MONTH(X5),Named_Rg[Currency],Named_Rg[Currency])*(Named_Rg[Month]=MONTH(X5))*(Named_Rg[Chg to €]))
```

Change the `,` to your `;` for your local settings.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thx, indeed inspecting the formula, `AND` wasn't a good solution. But I'm getting `#VALUE` for `Named_Rg[@[Currency]]`... :/

Comment: it is hard to test why without test data. @R3uK

Comment: Do you prefer a file or a basic table to reproduce it?

Comment: basic table @R3uK

Comment: Ok so there was to much `[]`, I'm trying to use it like this, but my header is actually `Entity Currency` and the `[]` come back automatically when I validate with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. I'm trying your solution with my sample (I've edited my question to include it!)

Comment: Something tells me you have the wrong formula, see edit @R3uK

Comment: I've tried the previous formula, I still get an error if I don't use it on the same row as the table and the `Named_Rg[@Currency]` always brings back the currency from the row the formula is entered in (and not the currency from the 1st IF)... I'm gonna try your other formula but I think it'll be the same problem.

Comment: Same issue as previously (I probably wasn't clear enough in my question). Furthermore I can't use your formula as it'll sum the Exchange Rates, and I have multiples rows for a Month/Currency/Entity combo.

Comment: Yes that is the limitation of using structured references.  You will need to change the `Named_Rg[@Currency]` to a cell reference, so in my case `G2` @r3uk

Comment: It did not sum the exchange rates, it only found the one that is = to that month in X5 I used SUMIF because it was easier and did not require an array formula.

Comment: Ok, so I definitely wasn't clear enough in my question! I can't use a Cell Ref as I want to have the value of the currency from the result lines of the first if... To apply the good exchange rate regarding the currency of each lines matching the first set of the criteria (<=Month). Is it clearer?

Comment: What are your expected results? Please put them in the original post.

Comment: I've added expected results, but note that I'll have multiple rows per month/currency.

Comment: You are so awesome! :) Nice workaround, I'll test it soon with a bigger data set, but from the structure I'm pretty confident that this will work! I'm just a bit perplexed by that test `Named_Rg[Currency],Named_Rg[Currency]` in the `SUMIFS`, is it what is allowing to keep an array as a result of the `SUMIFS`?

Comment: The sumproduct makes it iterate through the whole list, so the second one is the criteria that goes one by one. @R3uK

Comment: That's what I thought, but I would have never combined these functions like this on my own. I was just perplexed by the formula evaluation which isn't very clear! Thx very very much for your super valuable insight as always! ;)